# lidR, create table with numberofreturn by returnnumber in catalog

Tags: r, lidr

In a `LAScatalog` we can have the 5th first return, but how can i have this table if there is 7 return like this :

[image]

With this code i can generate this table with 4 return :

```r
LASfile <- system.file("extdata", "Megaplot.laz", package="lidR")
las = readLAS(LASfile)

tab <- table(las$ReturnNumber, las$NumberOfReturns)
tab

#>        1     2     3     4
#>  1 34337 17417  3670   332
#>  2     0 17474  3681   338
#>  3     0     0  3661   338
#>  4     0     0     0   342
```

But how can i have this table with 7 return on a catalog like the picture ?

Comment: You question is unclear to me. Please include some example of what you want to do. What do you want to show us with the image of the table?

Answer (score 1):

It is unclear what you are asking. This question seems to be about R not about lidR. If you want to force your table to be 7x7 you can do it this way but I'm not sure I answered the question.

```r
rn = factor(las$ReturnNumber, levels = 1:7)
nor = factor(las$NumberOfReturns, levels = 1:7)
tab <- table(rn, nor)
tab
#> rn     1     2     3     4     5     6     7
#>  1 34337 17417  3670   332     0     0     0
#>  2     0 17474  3681   338     0     0     0
#>  3     0     0  3661   338     0     0     0
#>  4     0     0     0   342     0     0     0
#>  5     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  6     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
#>  7     0     0     0     0     0     0     0
```

Comment: I am indeed confused in my question. My personal data contains laz files which have 7 returns. When I create the catalog, the summary only tells me the first 5 returns whereas if I look at the laz files individually I can create a matrix of the number of returns by return number of 7x7 whereas I cannot have this information directly in the catalog because it does not return the 7 returns just the first 5.
The code I sent was just for example on lidR package data. Am I clearer?

Comment: Please edit you question. Print your LASscatalog, Ask a question corresponding the problem. Show a code that involve a LAScatalog. Remove your image that is not related to your question. Remove your code snippet that is not related to the question.